# Identify the user who updated the record in a particular table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to know how can I take a user that modified a table/row and save this information into some temp log table.

Is it possible?

Thanks !

Comment: It depends in the database, but generally to see who modified a table (added a column, change a datatype), you need a DDL trigger. To see who changed data you need a standard trigger. These need to be installed beforehand. You can't find out afterwards.

Comment: See [SQL Server after update trigger](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35341698/1110897)

Comment: Built-In Change Tracking might also help: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933875.aspx

Comment: You could implement audit tables, e.g. [Quick And Easy Audit Tables - Dave Britten](http://dave.brittens.org/blog/quick-and-easy-audit-tables.html)