# How to add updateTime col to sql server 2017

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have DB and i insert createdTime col with getDate and it work fine.
now i want to add col "Update time", how i do it? Thanks!!!

Comment: You need a trigger for `updatetime` in SQL Server (or you need to set the value explicitly in the `update` statement).

Answer (score 1):

As @[Gordon Linof](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57957130/how-to-add-updatetime-col-to-sql-server-2017#comment102326030_57957130) stated by commenting your question, you can achieve this by using a **[trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)**.

Here you can find practical example:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[xxx_update] ON [dbo].[MYTABLE]
FOR UPDATE
AS
BEGIN

    UPDATE MYTABLE
    SET mytable.CHANGED_ON = GETDATE()
        ,CHANGED_BY = USER_NAME(USER_ID())
    FROM inserted
    WHERE MYTABLE.ID = inserted.ID

END
```

Source: [SQL Server after update trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25568526/sql-server-after-update-trigger)

Anyhow, i would prefer to let the application update the `CHANGED_ON` column while running the update statement.

Comment: You left out the join between `mytable` and `inserted`.

Answer (score 0):

I found easy way to do this:

1.Add col dataModified to you table

2.Write this code

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_update_my_table on my_table FOR UPDATE AS            
BEGIN
    UPDATE my_table
    SET dataModified=getdate()
    FROM my_table INNER JOIN deleted d
    on my_table.id = d.id
END
```

Comment: That's the same answer you got 7 hours ago from B3S.

Comment: No its not the same, i try it and it not work. my Solution is very clear and work.